# why width is not working in table-cell?

Tags: html, css

I need the following output with the given html, i used `display:table` property with `ul ul` and `display:table-cell` property with their `li` childeren, every `ul ul` has four child expect last `ul ul`, i already set the width of every `li` child of `ul ul`, but its not working with last raw, I dont want to edit my html, please help me, why its happening. Thanks in advance

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmkbxz68/)

**Expect output : -**

---

[image]

**Result I am getting:-**

---

[image]

**Html:-**

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">31</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">32</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">33</a></li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:-**

```
 ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}
div > ul{
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}
div > ul > li {
  width: auto;
}
div > ul ul{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
div > ul ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 0.9;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: with out empty `<li></li>` http://jsfiddle.net/bmkbxz68/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another empty `<li></li>` to your last row and it will be fixed, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">31</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">32</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">33</a></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">13</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">14</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">23</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">24</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">31</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">32</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">33</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> </a></li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

because u missed the cell in thrid row

Comment: np when i replied there was no answer ,some time people answer same time :)

Answer (score 1):

you just have to main the length of li

```
<ul><li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmkbxz68/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Without adding any `li`, Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/kjbtrg49/)

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
}
div > ul{
    display: block;    
    width: 100%;
}
div > ul > li {
  width: auto;
}
div > ul ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 0.9;
  padding: 5px 20px;  
}
```

Comment: your answer is working without adding any next li, @stanze, thanks :)